# Export all PDFs in directory

Tags: pdf

Is there any way to batch export PDFs, instead of going through each one and going Export as PDF? I was thinking there must be some utility I can run from terminal.

This is to basically get around an issue with Preview having some issues displaying unrendered equations - if I export the PDF from within Preview there are no issues viewing it.

Comment: To what format do you want to export the PDF's?

Comment: What is the original format of the document? Are the problems fixed if you open the faulty PDF in Preview and re-save as PDF? These steps can likely be automated.

Comment: they are PDFs - and yes they are fixed  if I open them and re-save them. I was thinking along the lines of automation, but I'm more comfortable in terminal.